# cheerio js memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, cheerio

I'm using cheerio to parse the results of [wikipedia api](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/html/)
I'm experiencing problems regarding memory.
This is the code in question

```
for (let response of responses) {
    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
      throw new Error('Received status: [%s] with message: [%s]', response.statusCode, response.message);
    }
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
    $('table.infobox').find('tr').each(function () {
      const key = $(this).find('th').text().replace(/\u00A0/g, ' ').trim().toLowerCase();
      console.log(key);
    });     
}
```

After a number of loops the memory used by the script doesn't get deallocated.
If I remove this section

```
$('table.infobox').find('tr').each(function () {
  const key = $(this).find('th').text().replace(/\u00A0/g, ' ').trim().toLowerCase();
  console.log(key);
});
```

Everything works great and the memory gets deallocated. Am I using cheerio wrong? Do you see anything in this piece of code that would cause memory leaks?

I'm using `cheerio@0.20.0` with `node 5.3.0`

Comment: does it deallocate if you remove the const key and console log but keep the loop?

Comment: @juvian no it doesn't. Moreover if it did, then something would  be really broken since I'm using `const` and not `var` where hoisting would pose as a liability. I tried it though just to be sure

Comment: I guess something must be broken with cheerio. I used whaco instead (same api, so I just replaced the import) and now it's stable.

Comment: well, good you found another way

Comment: Yeah sure. That was the ultimate goal, but it still bothers me that I don't know what's the problem with cheerio. Anyway I'm gonna leave this open just in case someone knows. Thanks for your help

Comment: Old post, but I feel like we're missing a [mcve] here. Was the leak ever reproducible or resolved?